# Require main in Electron

Tags: node.js, electron, require

In an electron app I have

```
exports.sayWord = function(){
    console.log("some word")
};
```

in main.js. Now, in `renderer.js`, I have

```
const main = require('./main.js');
```

But when I run the app and open the devtools I have the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sean/elecapp/main.js:47:4)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sean/elecapp/main.js:70:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sean/elecapp/renderer.js:20:14)
```

Line 47 is:

```
app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

but this does not make sense because the window is created, so obviously electron knew what `app` an `createWindow` were. I suspect that the problem has something to do with the fact that I am requiring `main.js` because I put the function `sayWord` in other files and when I required those nothing was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the error is because the main-process and the renderer-process do not have access to the same modules. For example `app` can be accessed in the main-process directly via `const {app} = require("electron")`, but in the renderer you can only access a proxy object via `const {app} = require("electron").remote`. But you shouldn't use `remote.app` either to fix your problem. If you were to modify your main.js script to run on both main-process and renderer-process, you would probably create a loop of creating new windows!

You should outsource the `sayWord` to a different file. If you plan to send data between main and renderer, then I would suggest to use [ipcMain](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-main.md) and [ipcRenderer](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-renderer.md) instead.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you right this is your first electron project and you cant create your index.html?

This is the main.js code I use. It will load the index.html in the same folder as start website. you don´t need to import main.js in the index.html

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, Tray, globalShortcut} = require('electron')
// this should be placed at top of main.js to handle setup events quickly
if (handleSquirrelEvent(app)) {
    // squirrel event handled and app will exit in 1000ms, so don't do anything else
    return;
}

const packager = require('electron-packager');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const loop = require('serial-loop');
const simpleTimestamp = require('simple-timestamp');


// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win




function createWindow () {

  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 980,
    height: 620,
    resizable: true,
    maximizable: true,
    center: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    } // webPreferences
  }) //  win = new BrowserWindow({




  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))

  // Open the DevTools.
//  win.webContents.openDevTools()

// mit zurück taste kann man auch in app zurück gehen
win.on('app-command', (e, cmd) => {
  // Navigate the window back when the user hits their mouse back button
  if (cmd === 'browser-backward' && win.webContents.canGoBack()) {
    win.webContents.goBack()
  }
})


  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', () => {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    win = null
  })
}


// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)





// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()

  }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.













function handleSquirrelEvent(application) {
    if (process.argv.length === 1) {
        return false;
    }

    const ChildProcess = require('child_process');
    const path = require('path');

    const appFolder = path.resolve(process.execPath, '..');
    const rootAtomFolder = path.resolve(appFolder, '..');
    const updateDotExe = path.resolve(path.join(rootAtomFolder, 'Update.exe'));
    const exeName = path.basename(process.execPath);

    const spawn = function(command, args) {
        let spawnedProcess, error;

        try {
            spawnedProcess = ChildProcess.spawn(command, args, {
                detached: true
            });
        } catch (error) {}

        return spawnedProcess;
    };

    const spawnUpdate = function(args) {
        return spawn(updateDotExe, args);
    };

    const squirrelEvent = process.argv[1];
    switch (squirrelEvent) {
        case '--squirrel-install':
        case '--squirrel-updated':
            // Optionally do things such as:
            // - Add your .exe to the PATH
            // - Write to the registry for things like file associations and
            //   explorer context menus

            // Install desktop and start menu shortcuts
            spawnUpdate(['--createShortcut', exeName]);

            setTimeout(application.quit, 1000);
            return true;

        case '--squirrel-uninstall':
            // Undo anything you did in the --squirrel-install and
            // --squirrel-updated handlers

            // Remove desktop and start menu shortcuts
            spawnUpdate(['--removeShortcut', exeName]);

            setTimeout(application.quit, 1000);
            return true;

        case '--squirrel-obsolete':
            // This is called on the outgoing version of your app before
            // we update to the new version - it's the opposite of
            // --squirrel-updated

            application.quit();
            return true;
    }
};
```